# Feature Differences between WordPress.com and Hosting on your Own Server?

Tags: plugins, wordpress.com-hosting, hosting

I created a new blog using WordPress.com  and obviously it got hosted on their server. But what I notice is that few features are not visible in this version as compared to the WordPress PHP script that I downloaded and hosted on my server.

For example: the Plugins options is not visible anywhere from where I can upload any plugin.

Is the online version a degraded editon of the original WordPress script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress.com is running the same code that you can download for free at WordPress.org ... the biggest difference is that .com is run by a for-profit company and .org is maintained by a non-profit community.

WordPress.com, as a for-profit enterprise, has certain features disabled (for security purposes) and certain features limited so that users can buy in to "premium" packages.  Specifically:

- You cannot upload or install custom themes (custom code could damage the multi-site environment
- You cannot upload or install custom plug-ins (for the same reasons as above)
- You must pay extra to direct traffic from your own domain to your WordPress.com site (a self-hosted site can use any domain you want)
- You cannon have an ad-free website on WordPress.com without paying extra (ad revenue supports the site)

Some bonus features you get from WordPress.com

- You'll *always* be running the latest version of the software without the need to update
- Your site will be automatically backed up by WordPress.com's servers
- You can pay extra to use VideoPress for hosting your own videos (doing this yourself requires a separate server in addition to your custom website host)
- Akismet and stats are built-in to the site (though you can add these for free with your own site).

Answer (score 1):

It is a slightly modified version of WordPress Multi-site. They turn off/hide some functions to increase stability since they are also on the hook for support. This is not uncommon for people that are hosting a large WordPress Multi-Site install to do.

Ultimately many new features of WordPress are first seen on wordpress.com then get rolled into the next version of WordPress.